# Can't Append to Array of Custom Protocol in Struct - Swift

Tags: swift, protocols

This is some demo code that demonstrates the issue.

```
protocol Test {}
struct Conforms: Test {}    
struct Testing {
    var t: [Test]
    //The following throws an error
    t.append(Conforms())
}
```

If the array is created outside of the Struct, I am able to append. Inside the Struct however, this error occurs.

Comment: It doesn't "throw an error". It simply doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is **Expected Declaration**.

You can't have free floating code in a structure.  It needs to be inside of a function:

```
protocol Test {}

struct Conforms: Test {}

struct Testing {
    var t: [Test] = []

    mutating func foo() {
        t.append(Conforms())
    }
}

var testing = Testing()
testing.foo()
```